# contacts could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

> when i am trying to connect with database i'm getting this error,
> could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table
> i've created a contact database table in phpmyadmin, and fist column marked it as primary key,auto_increment
> i've also tried by adding dummy data in the table for the first row

```
C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:833: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    class Contacts(db.Model):
  File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py", line 67, in __init__
    super(NameMetaMixin, cls).__init__(name, bases, d)
  File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py", line 121, in __init__
    super(BindMetaMixin, cls).__init__(name, bases, d)
  File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\api.py", line 76, in __init__
    _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 131, in _as_declarative
    _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(cls, classname, dict_)
  File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 160, in setup_mapping
    cfg_cls(cls_, classname, dict_)
  File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 194, in __init__
    self._early_mapping()
  File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 199, in _early_mapping
    self.map()
  File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 695, in map
    self.cls.__mapper__ = mp_ = mapper_cls(
  File "<string>", line 2, in mapper
  File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 139, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 723, in __init__
    self._configure_pks()
  File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 1409, in _configure_pks
    raise sa_exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class Contacts->contacts could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'contacts'


My model:

app= Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/coadingthuder'
db=SQLAlchemy(app)


class Contacts(db.Model):
    """s.no name email phone_num mes date"""
    name = db.Column(db.String(80),  nullable =False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20),  nullable =False)
    phone_num = db.Column(db.String(12),  nullable =False)
    mes = db.Column(db.String(12),  nullable =False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable =True)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs:

"Most ORMs require that objects have some kind of primary key defined because the object in memory must correspond to a uniquely identifiable row in the database table"

SQLAchemy (and Flask-SQLAlchemy) models [must declare a primary key](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key).  This can be done by adding a `primary_key=True` keyword argument to the column that you want to use as a primary key.

Flask-SQLAlchemy example:

```py
class Contacts(db.Model):
    """s.no name email phone_num mes date"""

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(80),  nullable =False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20),  nullable =False)
    phone_num = db.Column(db.String(12),  nullable =False)
    mes = db.Column(db.String(12),  nullable =False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable =True)
```

Integer primary keys will be automatically created and incremented with this configuration, so there is no need to add them yourself when creating new model instances.